# Django queryset : Calculate monthly average

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a sales model and i want to calculate the (Number of transactions)/(num of days) when grouped by `month`, `week`, `year`.

```
class SaleItem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True)
    bill = models.ForeignKey()
    item = models.ForeignKey('item')
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=3, default=0)
```

So if sales is grouped by month then this becomes (# transcations/# days in that month) for each month. Now if the sales if grouped by year this becomes (# transcations/# days in that year)

Currently i can get the number of transactions

```
aggregate = 'month' # parameter
# get number of transactions
SaleItem.objects.annotate(date=Trunc('bill__date', aggregate)).values('date').annotate(sales=Count('bill', distinct=True))
```

But how can i divide each count by the number of days in that group?

Comment: It might be a good idea to do that at the Python/Django side, you can use `calendar.month_range` to obtain the number of days for a given month.

Comment: I am worried if that wold reduce performance compared handling it at the db level.

Comment: why? This is just a linear operation. Since deserializing the data that we receive from the database, I would really be suprised if it is that significant. Yes aggregates, etc. should be calculated at the db side, but this is just "post-processing" the aggregate. A database does not per se handles data more efficient than Python/Django, it handles data aggregation, filtering, etc. better.

Comment: I see. Will try that route then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in SQL is possible (and not even that difficult). Getting the number of days in a month is RDBMS-specific though, and there is no generic Django database function to shield you from the various SQL implementations.

Django makes it very easy to wrap your own functions around SQL functions. For instance, for SQLite, you can define

```
class DaysInMonth(Func):
    output_field = IntegerField()
    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection):
        return super().as_sql(
            compiler, 
            connection,
            function='strftime',
            template='''
            %(function)s("%%%%d", 
            %(expressions)s, 
            "start of month", 
            "+1 month", 
            "-1 day")
            ''',
        )
```

Then you can use `DaysInMonth()` to divide your count by the number of days:

```
qs = (
    SaleItem.objects
        .annotate(date=Trunc('bill__date', aggregate))
        .values('date')
        .annotate(
            sales = Count('bill', distinct=True),
            sales_per_day = F('sales') / DaysInMonth('date')
        )
)
```

If a rounded-down integer is not sufficient and you need a decimal result, this is another hoop to jump through:

```
sales_per_day=ExpressionWrapper(
    Cast('sales', FloatField()) / DaysInMonth(F('date')), 
    DecimalField()
)
```

If, heaven forbid, you want to round in the database rather than in your template, you need another custom function:

```
class Round(Func):
  function = 'ROUND'
  output_field = FloatField()
  arity = 2

sales_per_day=Round(
    Cast('sales', FloatField()) / DaysInMonth(F('date')), 
    2 # decimal precision
)
```

So Django is really flexible, but as Willem said doing it in Python would save you some pain without losing significant performance (if any at all).